# Compare 2 Dataframe and Find the Matching Rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a master Dataframe as:

```
Time          Frq     Seq
12:46:17      4200.0  30700.0
12:49:29      4160.0  30690.0
12:46:18      3060.0  30700.0
12:46:18      3060.0  30700.0
12:46:19      3060.0  30700.0
12:46:20      3060.0  30700.0
12:46:20      4240.0  30700.0
12:46:19      4220.0  30700.0
12:46:18      4200.0  30700.0
12:46:18      4200.0  30700.0
12:46:38      3060.0  30700.0
12:43:04      4620.0  30701.0
12:46:38      4600.0  30701.0
12:46:05      4600.0  30701.0
12:46:37      3060.0  30700.0
12:48:35      3020.0  30690.0
```

and a child Dataframe as:

```
Frq     Seq
3060.0  30700.0
4600.0  30701.0
```

I want to collect the 1st occurrence of the Child Dataframe rows in Master Dataframe.

I want my Result Dataframe as:

```
Time          Frq     Seq
12:46:18      3060.0  30700.0
12:46:38      4600.0  30701.0
```

Comment: if `time` col is sorted, can you try `master.merge(child,on='Frq',suffixes=('','_')).groupby('Frq',as_index=False).first().reindex(master.columns,axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove duplicated in `master` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) - if omit parameter `on` it merge by intersection of columns names between both `DataFrame`s:

```
df = master.drop_duplicates(['Frq','Seq']).merge(child)
print (df)
       Time     Frq      Seq
0  12:46:18  3060.0  30700.0
1  12:46:38  4600.0  30701.0
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be grouping to get the firsts of each group to then index for the elements in your child dataframe:

```
first = master.groupby('Frq', as_index=False).first()
first[first.Frq.isin(child.Frq)]

#       Frq      Time      Seq
# 1  3060.0  12:46:18  30700.0
# 6  4600.0  12:46:38  30701.0
```

Answer (score 0):

- [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) -  to merge `master dataframe` and `child dataframe` with `inner join`.
- [`.drop_duplicate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) -  drop all `duplicate row` which has `Frq` and `Seq` column value is duplicate and keep only `first-row` value.
- [`df.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - Reset the index, or a level of it.

**Ex.**

```
df = master.merge(child, on=['Frq','Seq'],
     how='inner').drop_duplicates(['Frq','Seq'],keep= 'first').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

       Time     Frq      Seq
0  12:46:18  3060.0  30700.0
1  12:46:38  4600.0  30701.0
```